# Update View in Activity in response to recycler view item click

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, onitemclicklistener

I have this type of activity layout [image: Activity Layout]

In my layout, the yellow portion is my recyclerview, which is currently working as the expandable list.
Now in my scenario, when the user clicks on any item in the recyclerview than the layout changes in the activity shown by, green area and its child in the image.
Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the simple **[example](https://github.com/dharmakshetri/DigitalTrubineTechTest)** of pass value from recyclerview to activity using [eventbus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus). Try this maybe will help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback method.On click of item update UI using callback method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve this easily by using [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).